# Unable to use AJAX and AWS API Gateway to POST to an AWS Lambda Function

Tags: ajax, amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

My code is to act as a 'digital url book' in html. Users enter a url in a text field and click a submit button. Upon submission, the url is sent to an AWS lambda function that records the entry in a DynamoDB table. Another AWS Lambda function reads the table and displays the entries in a list to the user.

So far, I have been able to use AJAX and AWS API Gateway to GET the DynamoDB table contents for display, yet I am unable to configure the POST commands to call on the AWS lambda function that logs entries into the DynamoDB table. Whenever I run the code, AWS will show invocations on the Lambda function that reads the table, but never on the function that is to write/post to the table (even after clicking the submit button multiple times). The relevant portion of my html code is displayed below: upon loading the api it will GET the table contents and display them (no issue), yet the bottom portion after the click command does not work.

```
    <h1>Your URL List:</h1>
    <div id="sites">
    </div>
    <h1>Enter Your URL</h1>
    <form>
      <label for="urls">url</label>
      <textarea id="urls"></textarea>
      <button id="submitButton">Submit</button>
    </form>        
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var API_URL = 'https://wnq9rrdc37.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/prod/sites';
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: API_URL,
        
        success: function(data){
            $('#sites').html('');
            
            data.Items.forEach(function(urlbookItem){
            $('#sites').append('<p>' + urlbookItem.url + '</p>');
            })
        }
        });
    });
    $('#submitButton').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', 
            url: API_URL,        
            data: JSON.stringify({"url": $('#urls').val()}),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(data){
                location.reload();
            }
         });
        return false;
    });
 </script>
```

I have configured a mapping template in the integration request section of my POST command in AWS API Gateway. The template is as follows. Could this be the issue?

```
{
"url": $input.json('$.url');
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any insight on where I am going wrong with my code (permissions, html, ajax usage, api gateway, etc. - I am not sure).

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it didn't work?  Are you seeing an error message in the browser console?  In the logs?

Comment: When accessed there is one warning:

HTML1527: DOCTYPE expected. Consider adding a valid HTML5 doctype

When I click the submit button:

SEC7120: [CORS] The origin 'file://' did not find 'file://' in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header for cross-origin resource at ...

HTTP400: BAD REQUEST - The request could not be processed by the server due to invalid syntax. (XHR)POST - ...

This is strange to me as all GET/OPTIONS/POST sections under resources have " Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*' " in their Integration Response. I am unsure of how to proceed with this information.